# PDB does not match image Error - Remote debugging VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging, pdb-files

I have a C# VS 2019 MVC project. Debugging had been working fine since a month, and suddenly yesterday the debugging started to stop working and the breakpoints are no longer reached.

If I run debugging on my local server, it works. But on the remote debug server it doesn't work anymore.

[Modules list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zy9v.png)

In the list of loading I have this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\IHM_Admins.pdb: Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6def47b6\7017c765\assembly\dl3\9aabfede\3c9c3e51_572ed701\IHM_Admins.pdb: Impossible de trouver ou d'ouvrir le fichier PDB.
```

In the last position in the list I find:

```
C:\Users\Dev\source\repos\Project\IHM_Admins\obj\Debug\IHM_Admins.pdb: Les informations PDB ne correspondent pas à l'image.
```

(PDB does not match image Error)

However on the remote server, the 2nd file in the list is present.

I don't understand how it all works. Where does visual studio look for pdb files? On my local machine? Remote?

Of course, I tested all the basics:

- I am in local debug + publish
- The code is up to date on the server
- Code optimization is disabled
- I deleted the obj / bin folders (local + full remote folder) and regenerated + republished.
- I tried to restart remote server
- I tried to manually load the pdb, but although being in remote debugging, Visual Studio opens the explorer of my local computer. When I select the correct pdb file (the one in obj or bin) it gives me an error message telling me that it cannot find any matching file.
- The remote debugger is correctly configured and working. The project starts correctly and it is not a rights problem. I just have the breakpoints in error with the little warning telling me that they will not be reached without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my question;

It seems that VS publishes a "different version" on the remote server of the local version. For a reason that I do not know totally.

Yet the two version of the application are strictly identical, since I delete the remote directory, the local directory bin/obj and I regenerate everything and I publish.

Taking the PDB of the remote version and uploading it to my PC, then loading it it works. But I must do it for each version...